# How translate a static block in drupal 6?

Tags: 6, i18n-l10n

Does a variable exist that I can use to translate a static piece of text in a block?
For example:

```
<?php if($language==english): ?>
   do something...
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: You may want to look at http://drupal.org/project/translation_management to help you manage such code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
if ($user->language == 'ru') print 'Привет чувак!';
if ($user->language == 'en') print 'Hey Dude!';
```